# DataTable or IList? Which is better?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, linq-to-entities

I had following Service method -

```
public static DataTable GetBookDetails(BookEntities context)
    {
        DataTable dtBooks= new DataTable();
        dtBooks.TableName = "BookDetails";
        dtBooks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
        dtBooks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ISBN",typeof(string)));
        dtBooks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price",typeof(int)));
        dtBooks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Author",typeof(string)));
        IQueryable<Book> query = from b in context.Books.Include("Authors")
                                                                      .Include("Details/Price")
                                                                      .Include("Activity")
                                     where b.Activity.IsActive
                                     select b;
        if (query != null)
        {
            var sorted = query.ToArray().OrderByDescending(b => b.Activity.DateCreated);
            foreach (Book bb in sorted)
            {
                DataRow row = dtBooks.NewRow();
                row["Name"] = bb.Name;
                row["ISBN"] = bb.ISBN;
                row["Price"] = bb.Details.Price.CostOfBook;
                row["Author"] = bb.Authors.Name;
                dtBooks.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        else
            dtBooks= null;
        return dtBooks;
    }
```

My Questions are -

1. Is this an efficient way to get details or can I improve this method?
2. Someone suggested me to use IList instead of DataTable. Should I use this? If so, what are the advantages?
3. What's wrong in using DataTable?

Comment: Don't you have a relevant `Book` class which could be used ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896238/datatables-vs-ienumerablet

Comment: @RTRokzzz how you used Inculde (). if it is an extension method can you share it's code.

Comment: @faheemkhan: Inclued() is a Linq-To-Entity method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) vs [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)

`IList` represent collection that can be accessed by index. Nothing more.

`DataTable` also has similar capabilities, but it provides much more functionality (like more [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_events.aspx), [More features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_methods.aspx)) and is suitable where these features are required like representing Tabular data with advance capabilities (binding, custom sorting, grouping, event for row changed, cell added etc). All these extra features comes at extra overhead (of more memory requirement).

> Is this the efficient way to get details or I can improve this method?

You can slightly improve by using `IList`. The improvement is not in faster data access, but in not using extra features that `DataTable` provides.If you dont require access by index, you can further improve by using [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx).
You can further improve upon by using generics version. `IList<T>`, or `IEnumerable<T>` to save upon boxing/unboxing overhead.

> Someone suggested me to use IList instead of DataTable. Should I use this? If so, what are the advantages?

IList does not have overhead of plethora of features provided by `DataTable` other than access by index.

> Whats wrong in using DataTable?

Nothing wrong. `DataTable` is more suitable where advanced data access features are required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model a database or a database table then i suggest you go for **datatable** which is a class. **IList** is an interface and does not have the features of a datable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an efficient way to get details or can I improve this method?

You can use extension method instead direct calling static method. I think it looks cleaner.

Variable `query` could not be null.

> Someone suggested me to use IList instead of DataTable. Should I use this? If so, what are the advantages?

There are no big advantages of using IList instead of DataTable, unlike `IList<T>`(or `IEnumerable<T>`). `T` is another class with meaning of domain object `Book`.

Using `IList<T>` provides hard control over type T and respectively less errors, but it is more difficult to design.

> What's wrong in using DataTable?

You should understand that caller of your method does not know anything about concrete structure of `Rows` in your `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we try to keep things generic when working with services, if you are looking from that aspects go with IList. But, datatable provides more functionalities as @Tilak mentioned.