# BindingList vs DataTable vs List Collection

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to understand differences between these three collections.
My concept is to populate a datagridview using a datasource. In all of my methods which i will describe, i am getting the same result without any difference.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2();
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dt3();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(string name,int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
        [DisplayName("CustomerName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("CustomerAge")]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    //Method 1
    private BindingList<Foo> dt()
    {
        BindingList<Foo> tmp = new BindingList<Foo>();
        tmp.Add(new Foo (  "Dimitris", 28 ));
        tmp.Add(new Foo (  "Dio",  32 ));
        return tmp;
    }

    //Method 2
    private DataTable dt2()
    {
        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
        tmp.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)).Caption = "CustomerName";
        tmp.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int)).Caption = "CustomerAge";
        DataRow dr = null;

        dr = tmp.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Dimitris";
        dr["Age"] = 28;
        tmp.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = tmp.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Dio";
        dr["Age"] = 32;
        tmp.Rows.Add(dr);

        return tmp;
    }

    //Method 3
    private List<Foo> dt3()
    {
        List<Foo> tmp = new List<Foo>();
        tmp.Add(new Foo("Dimitris", 28));
        tmp.Add(new Foo("Dio", 32));
        return tmp;
    }
```

Is there any better way? Do they have any differences in performance? Which of the them are good practise for using?

Comment: _“Is there a better way?”_ … that depends on what you are doing. _”Do they have any differences in performance?”_ … probably, but in “most” cases, this difference would be negligible. _”Which of the them are good practise for using?”_ … Again, that depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Each approach has its own advantage/disadvantage, and IMHO there is NO…“this is the BEST” approach for ALL situations. Example, if you have limited resources, a `DataTable` may not be the best approach as it will (usually) consume more resources than a `List<T>`. You may want to take a look at [DataTables vs IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896238/datatables-vs-ienumerablet).

Comment: I have something to say about all three of these things. But I'm not a native English speaker. If you agree to listen my terrible English, I'll try to explain.

Comment: I need to populate a datagridview. With Example 10.000 rows

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Could you write your opinion on this issue to my Email: i122123@yandex.ru . I understand Russian well.

Comment: @eusaf - `List` uses one-way data-binding. / `BindingList` implements `IBindingList` interface with `ListChanged` event that create a two-way data-binding mechanism. / `DataTable` also implements two-way data-binding, but in addition, its rows implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: @eusataf - задай вопрос на ru.so

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I think such a question will be blocked.
Maybe still share your experience by Email.
Very necessary.
Thanks.
Or the answer in this question. Google(Yandex) translator seems to works fine.